# ProgressDialog covers whole screen

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'd like to show a ProgressDialog which covers whole screen. I mean when the dialog is showing, the UI shouldn't be touched or clicked or interacted. How to create a dialog like that?

Comment: with a simple dialog, background ui are inaccessible. why you want the the dialog to cover the whole screen besides that?

Comment: Because I want some UIs should wait for the loading task to finish to avoid the unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is already done by a normal ProgressDialog.
Just add `myProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`
this prevents the dialog from closing when the user clicks on the screen.
`myProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);` prevents the Dialog from closing on "back"-key

Comment: No, I mean it covers whole screen, not uncancelable. User still can cancel it. Just like this in JQuery http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Yes a normal ProgressDialog does this. In the Screenshot you can see the normal View is disabled when Dialog is showing. You need to set myProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); because otherwise the Dialog will disappear when the user clicks anywhere on the screen. http://www.java-samples.com/images/progress-bar-android.gif